# Changing the Type of the Custom field

Tags: acumatica

How can i change the Type of the Custom field in Acumatica?
I created a new custom field of "ComboBox" Type for the Sales Order Header Section.Now i would like to change its type to "TextEdit" so the user can manually enter any value in it. So far there are only few Sales order where user has entered the value in this field.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Combo boxes are stored in string fields in the database - you can therefore easily replace the control on the page with a text edit field. The simplest way is to remove the combo box from the layout editor, and then adding it back as a text box from the "Add Data Fields" tab. If you want to modify the properties of the field itself, you have to go to the Data Access section and modify the attributes of the field (PXDBString + remove PXStringList attribute if you have one). Lastly, if this is a field you were creating as part of your customization project, you might have to manually edit the Table node of the project XML (File -> View Project XML)

Comment: I tried the above and it has changed the datatype. But when i am using this field in the Generic Inquiry i am getting error "Unable to cast object of type"system.Int32" to type "System.string"..

Comment: Also, in the SQL database the type of this field is still (int, null)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using a PXStringList for the combo, not a PXIntList - you need to edit the attributes of the field to change it from PXDBInt to PXDBString, and also edit the <Table> xml of the project XML. The database field will *not* change its type automatically on your installation. You need to do it manually, but if you republish that customization elsewhere it will have the right type.